# Print text with delay using TimeMillis

Tags: java

So, i need for my homework to display a text, char by char with 2seconds delay using TimeMillis.

```
String rolyText = "Long long ago, in a galaxy far, far away!";

for (int i = 0; i < rolyText.length(); i++) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 2000) {

    }

System.out.print(rolyText.charAt(i));
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: `Thread.sleep(2000)`?

Comment: What is the problem with your current code ?

Comment: your code seems to be ok. What is ur problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pause use: [`java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#sleep(long))

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
```

To sleep for 1 minute:

```
TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);
```

If you want to sleep for 1 sec:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```